# Display cfcontent and html together

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe, coldfusion

I have the following:

```
<cfpdf action="read" name="myPdf" source="c:\test.pdf">
<cfcontent variable="#toBinary(myPdf)#" type="application/pdf" />
```

And it does display the pdf file correctly. But I need to add a few buttons to the page. I've tried the following, but Safari on the iPad doesn't display this very well:

```
<iframe width="550" height="600" src="c:\test.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Q: Can I display html before I display the cfcontent tag?

Comment: Is it the scrolling issue?

Comment: I believe the answer is, no.

Comment: *add a few buttons to the page* Just to clarify, you mean add to the parent page (not the iframe), correct? Also, have you looked at [other options from embedding pdf files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html).  (Nothing to do with the question, but you probably do not need the cfpdf "read". Instead use the cfcontent file attribute.)

Comment: @Leigh Thanks. The solution we used was the embed tag, which was from your comment.

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to post that as answer, when you get a chance. So it is easier for the next guy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the embed tag as @Leigh suggested in the comments.